# Why does std::is_convertible_v return true even though this conversion isn't legal?

Tags: c++, templates, implicit-conversion, type-traits

I'm working on a C++ project that requires the use of type introspection to determine what sort of object type a template is. In doing so, I ran into an unusual issue. I've isolated the root issue to a mismatch between what `std::is_convertible_v` says and what types are actually convertible to one another. Here's a reduced example that demonstrates the problem.

Here's a type called `LookForNested`, which has a template constructor that looks inside the template argument type for a nested type named `NestedType`.

```
struct LookForNested {
  /* Look inside the argument type for a nested type. This won't
   * compile if you invoke the constructor on a type that doesn't have
   * a nested type with name NestedType.
   */
  template <typename T> LookForNested(const T&) {
    typename T::NestedType x;
  }
};
```

Surprisingly, this `static_assert` fails, even though you cannot initialize a `LookForNested` with an integer:

```
static_assert(!std::is_convertible_v<int, LookForNested>, "Can't initialize with int");
```

The [documentation for `std::is_convertible`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_convertible) suggests that the check is done by seeing whether it would be possible to write a function that returns an `int` and has return type `LookForNested`. Just to confirm that, indeed, you couldn't do this, I coded up this function. As expected, it doesn't compile.

```
/* Attempt to initialize a LookForNested with an int; this fails. */
LookForNested returnAnInt() {
  return 137;
}
```

I'm now quite confused because

- the `std::is_convertible_v` trait suggests that you can indeed initialize a `LookForNested` with an `int`, but
- indeed, you cannot convert an `int` to a `LookForNested`.

(I'm using g++ (Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1) 7.4.0, by the way.)

My questions are as follows:

1. What is causing this discrepancy?
2. If I want to test whether an `int` is *really* convertible to a `LookForNested`, what should I use instead of `std::is_convertible_v`?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you expecting the conversion to fail because the constructor template cannot be _instantiated_? But that's not part of the question; the presence of the (unconstrained) declaration suffices to make the class appear to be constructible from, well, anything; no instantiations are performed to determine that. That's why we don't generally want unconstrained templates, and hence enable_if and concepts and all that.

Comment: @KerrekSB I hadn't paused to think about the distinction between "this code won't compile" and "this template function signature matches, but the template function can't be instantiated." That's probably the issue. I suppose this means I need to retrofit the constructor in my example with some sort of `std::enable_if` wizardry that ensures the signature won't match unless instantiation would succeed? Also, if that's the case, what is `std::is_convertible` doing internally that checks just the signature but doesn't do instantiations?

Comment: @templatetypedef, I don't have precise wording for you, but logically, an internal test such as `decltype(implicitly_convert_to<LookForNested>(declval<int>()))` wouldn't need to go further than the constructor signature to do SFINAE. The function in the question needs to generate code to do the conversion, which requires the body. I suppose the relevant text would make it clearer what the exact process is in the former.

Comment: If it helps, here's a mostly-from-scratch idea of what `is_convertible` does as far as I know (minus some checking for function/array types and void): https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/ju1NxB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. As Kerrek SB and chris mentioned in the comments, `std::is_convertible` only considers the constructor's *declaration*, not its *definition* - it does not perform template instantiation, hence the discrepancy.
2. You can still use `std::is_convertible`, but the constructor of `LookForNested` has to be changed in a way that shows its dependency on `T::NestedType` in its declaration.

You can either check if it exists at all:

```
template <typename T, typename T::NestedType* = nullptr>
LookForNested(const T&);
```

or perform more elaborate checks, like if it's default-constructible:

```
template <typename T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_default_constructible_v<typename T::NestedType>>* = nullptr>
LookForNested(const T&);
```

---

Complete example (https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/FT_eaX):

```
#include <type_traits>

struct LookForNested {
  /* Look inside the argument type for a nested type. This won't
   * compile if you invoke the constructor on a type that doesn't have
   * a nested type with name NestedType.
   */
  template <typename T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_default_constructible_v<typename T::NestedType>>* = nullptr>
  LookForNested(const T&) {
    typename T::NestedType x;
  }
};

struct Good {
    using NestedType = double;
};

struct Bad {};

static_assert(!std::is_convertible_v<int, LookForNested>, "Can't initialize with int");
static_assert(std::is_convertible_v<Good, LookForNested>, "Can initialize with struct which has NestedType");
static_assert(!std::is_convertible_v<Bad, LookForNested>, "Can't initialize with struct which does not have NestedType");
```